# Is it possible to repair a jpg that doesn't "look" broken?

Tags: images, hex

I have many photos that were recovered a long time ago, at the time I recovered them and everything looked fine, the thumbnails produced looked good. However now, 16 years later. I see that the images are cut off in places and sometimes have incorrect contrast in places.

I am wondering, as I have images that are still "good" if its possible to copy over some of the hex values from the good images onto the broken one?

[image]

Broken Image
[image: How to re]

Good Image
[image]

Comment: The two images seem totally different. How can you "fix" data from a different image?

Comment: I was hoping... in vien, that it might be similar to videos that share video headers. Never in my life have I tried to fix images before.

Comment: The headers/footers of files tend to be the same, yes, but you need to fix the actual data here, not the format. If the header were corrupted you probably wouldn't even be able to open the image at all. It seems more likely (but I really don't know) that you would be able to fix each photo by itself than that you could use another photo.

Comment: Ye I see. That makes very sad news :D I also highly doubt the files are corrupted all in the same way. Though stranger things have happened. I am not concerned about how they are fixed of course. I could remove the "correct" file, but wouldn't having a non-damaged file help in someway? Or its complete waste of cognitive space in this example? Hunting down the broken data I imagine is the way to fix the image?

Comment: I am no expert on this sort of thing but yes, I suspect it is indeed a waste of cognitive space as you put it :). It's sort of like saying "I have a song and am missing the last minute of it, how can I recreate the last minute of this song using this other song?"

Comment: I believe you summed it up well then... `As said, if the only thing that can assess the content of a piece of data is a human, then that's it. For typical fotographic content, e.g. cognitive vision through deep/convolutional neural networks might be an appropriate way to detect 4 kB of "unsuitable" data being decoded e.g. by a JPEG decoder.` Aka... fix it with photoshop as nothing else can do it :)?